# using the reflection API for takeing as an arguments for program, the names of other java classes

Tags: java

i want write a java program  that takes as arguments the names of other Java classes. For each class name,my program loads the corresponding class by using the reflection API.
but i don't know how can i do

Comment: What research have you done? Do you know how to pass arguments to a program? Have you researched class loading by name?

Comment: Based on current state of your question it may seem that you may be looking for `Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("full.name.of.SomeClass");`. If that is not what you meant then clarify your question.

Comment: yes i want use class.forname

Answer (score 0):

Just use Class class. For example

```
public void coolMethod(Class clazz) {...}
```